# Why do I need a delay when using a complicated keystroke?

Tags: calendar, applescript, icalendar, automator

I am creating an Applescript workflow to run in Calendar that involves moving an event to the next day.  The keyboard shortcut is ^⌥→ (control, option, right).  Therefore, I thought the following code would work:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Calendar" to activate
    key code 124 using {control down, option down}
end tell
```

However, it did not work.  After some tinkering, the following code works.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Calendar" to activate
    delay 2
    key down {control}
    key down {option}
    delay 2
    key code 124
    delay 2
    key up {control}
    key up {option}
    delay 2
end tell
```

What am I missing?  Why does a single key stroke/combination necessitate delays?

Comment: Scripting the user interface takes the long way around, so the system needs time (which varies) to send events to the application, the application needs time (which varies) to respond to an event, the system needs time to respond to that (which also varies), and so on.

Comment: What @red_menace said is right. You're manipulating the UI - which takes time.

If you want it faster you'll probably have to use what's documented in Calendar's scripting dictionary. It **does** have one - unless this is a different Calendar from the built in one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the name of your calendar, and the name of the event you wish to move, then:

```
tell application id "com.apple.iCal"
    tell the calendar named "Calendar_Name"
        tell (the first event whose summary = "Event_Title")
            set the [end date, start date] to [¬
                end date + 1 * days, ¬
                start date + 1 * days]
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Assuming you don't have either of these, then we'll have to turn to UI scripting, which I do grudgingly and as a last resort.  But as there doesn't seem to be another way to get information about which calendar item a user has currently selected in the application, I checked how reasonable the method was to obtain it this way, and this is what I came up with:

```
set text item delimiters to linefeed

tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents" to tell the ¬
        process "Calendar" to tell window 1 to tell the ¬
        splitter group 1 to tell its group 1 to tell the ¬
        UI element 1 to tell (every list where focused ¬
        of its every static text contains true) to tell ¬
        (static texts whose focused = true) to return the ¬
        text items of (contents of {help, description} ¬
        as text)
```

It's a mouthful.  Basically, it appears that when you're in month view<sup>†</sup>, each day of the month is a type of `ui element` called a `list`, which houses one `static text` object for each event scheduled for that day.  The accessibility information attached to the objects aren't useless, but they were likely done by some 16-year-old intern who just wanted his day to end.

It's the `static text` object that has the goodies, and thankfully, it updates its `focused` property to reflect whether or not it is selected (although, this appears to only be true for singular selections, so multiple batch fetching isn't immediately viable).

The bulk of that block is isolating the `static text` that reports itself to be `focused`, and when we finally get to it nested quite deeply under guard, it has two properties that contain everything we need...  But it's written in prose, so I'm going to leave this as a task to the reader to extract the relevant information.

To give you an idea, here's what it returns for the event I selected:

- **`help`** property: *"This event belongs to calendar "CK"."*

  This gives the calendar to which the event belongs.  This will vary between locales, but I think it should translate to more-or-less the same kind of usable information.  As a hint, it's useful that the calendar name is the only thing contained inside quotes, so that makes extraction clean and simple.
- **`description`** property: *"hello this is a
  story all about how my life got flipped, turned upside down.. Starts on S10Oct2020 at 0900 and ends at 1000."*

  This is slightly more awkward, but it does contain the name of the event, which is the only other thing we need.  It also contains the date and time, but you've already seen how to get and set those.  You can see two full stops after the word *"down"*: the first one was mine, and is part of the event's name; the second is where I would bisect the test and disregard the latter half, then store the first to use as a search term against the `summary` property that will match the appropriate event (provided it is uniquely named).

<sup>†</sup><sub>*The UI script was written with the Calendar app in month view, and it almost certainly won't work in any other view, although you're free to give it a try.  If I have time, I may try out other views to allow more flexibility, but my time is really limited as of late, so you may have to use what I've demonstrated here and apply it yourself.*</sub>

Comment: While this _code_ does work, in that it does move an _event_ to the next day, it targets the first _event_ of the _named event_ which could be an _event_ from years ago on the calendar. How could this be modified to act on the selected _event_, as the **UI Scripting** of the OP does?

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for highlighting this.  I'll add something quickly now, and try and update with specifics if I have time.